# SQL SUM GROUP BY where id changed over time

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a simple task in sql to sum values by month according to IDs:

SELECT ID, sum(Monthly_value) 
FROM my_database
GROUP By ID

However my data is collected for several years and in the meantime several ID values have changed and several ID's developed a corresponding new business and exist under two ID,s and in these limited cases I need to sum them as one.

I am also receiving a growing list with the pairs of  ID's that need to be treated as one:

- old and corresponding new ID's I am requested to sum(Monthly_value) for these old and new id's
- two IDs to be treated as one.

Is there a simple way to amend this code so that I do not edit old ID's in the original database and in some cases I could sum values for several IDs whereas for most cases I would sum, group by one ID.

I am not supposed to physically replace old with new IDs because other query may still use it. I may use another table, a dictionary where one ID may have a corresponding another ID, both of which need to be summed up. I am not sure in which direction to go, perhaps

====Here I am trying but have no idea how to make sense.======

```
SELECT ID, sum(Monthly_value), 
FROM my_database LEFT JOIN my_double_id_cases ON my.database.ID=my_double_id_cases.ID;
GROUP By 
Case
NOT NULL my_double_id_cases.SecondaryID
(I do not know what to do to get two ID's to be aggregated, no idea whatsoever) 
Else 
ID
```

## ....

The data is very simple, I removed the time issue from my questiton:

```
Id, date, value 
112233,21-10-2012,23 231
232123,20-11-2012,11 234
112233,11-12-2012,21 211
112233,12-12-2013,14 110
887755,12-12-2013,14 110
```

....(plenty of records, for several years)...

suddenly in the mid of 2013 I am told that 112233 will now be 001122 (also the name has changed, there is really no way to aggregate on but an external list, a dictionary of corresponding IDs vs new ID's

The expected result would be.

```
ID;  Sum (eg. for year 2014)
001122; 10 021 213 (includes also 112233 values, ID changed mid 2014) 
232123;  8 323 111 (includes also 887755 values, two IDs are in fact one entity) 

other ID's, the majority of them are  summed up like in the initial query (group by ID)
```

And at the end of the day 232123 and 887755 should be summed up together as well. 
Other IDs, if not in my "dictionary",  are to be summed as usual.

=======Platform=======

I am using ACE SQL, (practically it is, if I am not wrong, MS Access). My code is in a VBA macro and my tables in an Excel file.

======================

I will greatly appreciate all your help.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, are you using SQL Server or MS Access?  They have different capabilities and syntax.

Comment: I am sorry, I added more information according to your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a table with the list of new and old ids:

```
SELECT isnull(n.newid,myd.ID) ID, sum(myd.Monthly_value) FROM my_database myd left join newoldids n on n.oldid = myd.id
GROUP By isnull(n.newid,myd.ID)
```

Comment: Dear Paolo I understand that my dictionary must have both old and new  value translated to newID and it souns reasonable and valid solution  but how can i account for Id with no change. not prezent in my dictipnary?

 Thank you for  this good idea.

Comment: see my edit and check it against your structure. with the left join you get all the rows and not only the one with changes. also check the performance issues.

Comment: Thank you. I am now on my mobile will test it and get back my reput too low to plus you You are great

Comment: Dear Paolo, you are great. The solution works well. Instead of isnull I had to use the MSAccess iif(isnull(n.newid),.... As for performance, it takes negligibly longer. For my needs it is perfect. Again I am very grateful for your help.

Answer (score -1):

It might be easiest to use a new table where all IDs that should be grouped are different attributes for one row; that would eliminate the need for any crazy manipulations, since you could just sum over the new ID that represents all the others.

Comment: It gives me an idea to build dynamically new column with new kind of id (concatenated???) to be used for aggregation IF id found in my dictionary table (table of changes) IF not found old id iż used.

Thanks for  your help